# Run java program sing Cmd

Tags: java

I'm trying to run Java program using `cmd`.

When I compile that file using

```
javac helloworld.java
```

It works perfectly but when I try to run that file using

```
java helloworld
```

I get an error:

> couldn't find or load main class.

even though my I put my `javac` path in class path in system variables and `javac` working correctly.

After searching on how I can fix it I found that I can use

```
java -cp . helloworld
```

because it let you to find `.class` file.

and it works but I know that I can run java program without this `-cp` so what this for and how I can run my program without it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-cp specifies the Java classpath for the JRE you are attempting to start. Look for an environment variable `CLASSPATH` and add `'.'`.

Answer (score 1):

`-cp` is used to set the `classpath` for the `jar` file, this flag is same as `importing` a jar file to `eclipse` and then use it.
If you want to run without this flag, use should set the classpath first beforing running.

```
export CLASSPATH=path/to/your/jarfile.jar
```

If you already have some classpath set

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:path/to/your/jarfile.jar
```

If you want to include current directory

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:path/to/your/jarfile.jar:.
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, you can set the CLASSPATH. However, a much better approach is to bundle the .class files in a JAR ans user java -jar nameofthejar.jar.